# See UPDATE permissions at column-level for all tables in a database

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a table of metadata, listing every variable in every table in my database, which when a variable is flagged as 'Released' it triggers a stored procedure to deny `UPDATE` permissions on that field in its respective table, and also deny `INSERT` and `DELETE` permissions on the table as a whole, for 3 specific Users everytime.

It works perfectly! But I'd like some kind of checking method that I can run every so often to confirm that all released variables have had their `UPDATE` permissions removed for these 3 Users - so I can check no pesky admins have gone in and changed them sometime!

Is there a way I can see the fields in every table in a database, along with their UPDATE permissions for each User, so then I can compare it to my metadata table to confirm Released columns have indeed had their `UPDATE` permissions altered?

I am using SSMS v17.9.

Comment: Why not remove permissions from "pesky admins" if they've no rights to be doing this?

Comment: @Vérace It's also just to keep ensuring the triggers and procedures haven't failed at some point.

Comment: How does one put "variables" in tables? Do you mean columns?

Comment: @MichaelGreen Of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All this information is the the catalog views.  Here's a query to get you started:

```
select schema_name(t.schema_id) schema_name, 
       t.name table_name, 
       c.name column_name, 
       p.permission_name,
       p.state_desc 
from sys.tables t
join sys.columns c
  on t.object_id = c.object_id
join sys.database_permissions p
  on c.object_id = p.major_id
 and c.column_id = p.minor_id
where p.class_desc = 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN'
```